# why redirecting to landing page when i click on forgot password in angular using azure?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-msal

I have landing page in that i have 2 buttons. Employee Login(Azure AD) and External Login (Azure B2C) when i click on External login it is navigating to Azure B2C login and soon when i click on Forgot Password it is redirecting to landing page and then redirecting to Reset Password page but problem is that only soon when i click on Forgot Password it should redirect direct to Reset Password.
It should not navigate to landing page. Anyone has solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Deepashree. Could you please verify the reply URL and also are you using custom policy or user flow? Please refer this document for more information- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-angular-spa

Comment: Hi... Did you happen to get a resolution for this?